# Geometry inquiry on inversion.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-transformation

Let $ABCD$ be a quadrilateral with an inscribed circle $\omega$ which is tangent
to the sides $AB, BC, CD, DA$ at points $P, Q, R, S$ respectively. We want
to show that $AC, BD, PR, QS$ meet at one point. Let $PR ∩ QS = X$. Let $CX$ meet the circle again at points $G$ and $H$.

> Describe an inversion which maps $P → R, Q → S$. What happens
> to $G$ and $H$?

I might be getting confused here but we must have the centre of inversion on the lines $PR$ and $QS$, which gives us point $X$. But $X$ is clearly impossible to be the centre of inversion. Was there some flaw in my logic? Any help is appreciated.

Geogebra screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In an inversion of a given power $K$ and center $X$ we have two cases depending on the sign of $K$. In case of a positive $K$, we transform a point $P$ into $P^*$ with $XP\cdot XP^*=K$, and $P,P^*$ are on the same ray from $X$. It is useful to think of $XP$ and $XP^*$ as signed distances for some or any direction chosen on the line $XP$.

In this sense, if $K<0$, the points $P,P^*$ are on the line $XP=XP^*$, but on different / opposite rays.

In our case, since the points $P,Q,R,S$ are concyclic, we have - using only positive lengths
$$
|XP|\cdot |XR| = |XQ|\cdot |XS|:=K\ .
$$
Using also signs, we have:
$$
XP\cdot XR=XQ\cdot XS=-K\ .
$$
We use this $-K$ as power for an inversion.
Then $P^*=R$, $R^*=P$ and $Q^*=S$, $S^*=Q$.
The circle $\odot(PQRS)$ is thus invariated as a set of points.

---

In the notations of the $OP$, we have $G^*=H$ and $H^*=G$, since the points $G,H,X$ are colinear, and $G,H$ are on the invariated circle on the one and the other side of the point $X$.

---

To illustrate further properties of this inversion (denoted by $*$), let us consider further lines and circles and their transforms:

- Let $\Xi$ the point of intersection of the circles $\odot(XPQ)$ and $\odot(XRS)$. Then the circle $\odot(XPQ)$ through the center $X$ of inversion is transformed in the line $X^* P^*Q^*=\infty RS$.
  Similarly, the circle $\odot(XRS)$ is transformed in the line $PQ$. The second intersection of the two circles, is a point which is transformed in a point on the intersection of the lines $RS$ and $PQ$, which is not $X^*=\infty$, so this point is
  $$
  \Xi ^*=PQ\cap RS\ .
  $$
  [image: mse 4783594 proof by inversion]
- It may be a fun experiment to apply the Pascal theorem on $QQSRRP$.
  Then the three intersections $QQ\cap RR=C$, $QS\cap RP=X$, $SR\cap PQ=\Xi^*$
  are colinear. This shows $C,X,\Xi^*$ colinear.
- With a cyclic permutation of variables so that $ABCD$ becomes $CDAB$ we apply Pascal's theorem on $SSQPPR$. So the three intersections
  $SS\cap PP=A$, $SQ\cap PR=X$, $QP\cap RS=\Xi^*$
  are colinear. This shows $A,X,\Xi^*$ colinear.
- In this moment we already have five points on a line, $X,\Xi,\Xi^*,A,C$.
  So $AC$ passes through $X$. In a similar manner, $BC$ also passes through $X$.
  This would be one way to conclude.
- One can show that $\odot(X\Xi O\Upsilon)$ is a circle with diameter $XO$.

---

An other approach is to consider the transforms $A^*,B^*,C^*,D^*$ also in the picture:

[image: mse 4783594]

We consider the point $A=SS\cap PP$. (Here $SS$ and $PP$ are the tangents in $S,P$ of the given circle $\omega=\odot(PQRS)$.) Its transform $A^*$ is then on the transformed curves. $SS$ goes into a circle through $X$ and $S^*=Q$, which is tangent to $\omega$ in $Q$. But at this point $\omega$ is also tangent to $BQC$. So we obtain the circle $\odot(XA^*Q)$ tangent in $Q$ to $BC$. Similarly, the circle $\odot(XA^*R)$ is tangent in $R$ to $CD$. But the circle through $X$ tangent in $R$ to $CD$ is uniquely determined, its center is on $OR$ and the perpendicular bisector of $XR$. So $B^*$ is also on this circle. (Use cyclic permutation of the letters and the same argument.)

So we obtain the above four circles:
$\odot(XA^*RB^*)$,
$\odot(XB^*SC^*)$,
$\odot(XC^*PD^*)$,
$\odot(XD^*QA^*)$.

Denote by $O_P\in OP$, $O_Q\in OQ$, $O_R\in OR$, $O_S\in OS$ the four centers of the four circles,
the index is the touching point with the given quadrilateral.

The triangles
$\Delta ORP$ and
$\Delta O_PXP$ are isosceles in $O,O_P$, and share the same angle $P$.
So they are similar, this gives $OP\| XO_R$. In a similar manner
$OQ\| XO_S$, $OR\|XO_P$, $OS\|XO_R$.
We obtain two parallelograms, $OO_PXO_R$ and $OO_QXO_S$, with intersection of diagonals in their mid point, the middle of $OX$, denoted by $\Pi$.
This makes $O_PO_QO_RO_S$ also a parallelogram with intersection of diagonals in their mid point $\Pi$.

[image: mse 4783594 position of the centers of the four circles]

The points $X,A^*$ are on the two circles
$\odot(O_Q)=\odot(XQA^*)$ and
$\odot(O_R)=\odot(XRA^*)$, so the radical axis $XA^*$ is perpendicular on the centers line. We obtain:
$$
XA^*\perp O_QO_R\ \|\ O_SO_P\perp XC^*\ .
$$
So the lines $XA^*$ and $XC^*$ have the same direction, the direction perpendicular on $O_QO_R\|O_SO_P$, they have also a common point, so they coincide. We obtain the collinearity of $X,A^*C^*$, and thus of $X;A,A^*;C,C^*$.

$\square$